# Import data, transform it and insert into sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, fetch

I'm trying to import API from a game, modify the data to save it into my database.
The data I import gives me all the Sell orders of all the item and I only want to keep the cheapest price before inserting it into my DB.

Here is the code :

```
async function updateJitaMarket() {
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000002/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=sell&page=1'),
    fetch('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000002/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=sell&page=2'),
    fetch('https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000002/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=sell&page=3')
]).then(function(responses) {
    //Get a JSON object from each of the response
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then (async function (data) {
    //log the data to the console
    // You would do something with both sets of data here
    data = data[0];
    var newData = [];
    for (var i=0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        const found = newData.some(el => el.item_id === data[i].item_id);
        if(!found) {
            newData.push({
                duration: data[i].duration,
                is_buy_order: data[i].is_buy_order,
                issued: data[i].issued,
                location_id: data[i].location_id,
                min_volume: data[i].min_volume,
                order_id: data[i].order_id,
                price: data[i].price,                   
                range: data[i].range,
                system_id: data[i].system_id,
                type_id: data[i].type_id,
                volume_remain: data[i].volume_remain,
                volume_total: data[i].volume_total                  
            });
        }
        if(found) {
            for(var j=0; j < newData.length; j++) {
                if(newData[j].type_id === data[i].type_id && newData[j].price > data[i].price) {
                    newData[j].price = data[i].price;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    const result = await pool.query("DELETE FROM jita_market");
    const result1 = await pool.query("INSERT INTO jita_market SET ?", newData); 
    return newData;
}).catch(function (error) {
    // if there's an error, log it
    console.log(error);
});
```

It returns me a syntax error near the '?'.

Error: Erreur de syntaxe près de '?' à la ligne 1
at PromisePool.query (F:\WAMP\www\Esparto2Backend\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:330:22)
at F:\WAMP\www\Esparto2Backend\app\models\appModel2.js:139:30
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: "Erreur de syntaxe près de '?' à la ligne 1"
}

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please check the syntax of the INSERT statement, it should not use SET https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html.

Comment: Also the placeholders `?` are intended to be replaced by a single value, not a object structure https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#first-query

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments.

Instead of building an array along, I make sql request to check if item_id is already is bdd / update bdd if price is higher in BDD or insert in BDD if item_id doesn't exit. This works perfectly fine :)